# CSS Background Images with Flask

Tags: html, css, flask, background-image

I have read other questions about getting background images in flask to show, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me and I get a 404 error(127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018 15:13:33] "GET /img/showcase.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 -). The jpeg image I want to set as the background is located in the static folder and called showcase.jpeg. Here is my code. Any suggestions? Here's the HTML Link to my style.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}">
```

CSS FILE:

```
#showcase{
  background-image: url({{ url_for ('static', filename = 'showcase.jpeg') }});
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0DXl.png)

Comment: One of the suggested answers was to put the static folder next to the flask file, but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you show all the files and the directory tree structure? That would help a lot.

Comment: Have you checked in your inspector tools to see that Jinja is rendering the URL in the CSS layer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSS files are read as static files, so you shouldn't be using the url_for method in your CSS.

If your file structure is:

```
static
  -img
  -css
```

Use `background-image: url(../img/showcase.jpeg)`

[Relevant SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221045/handling-urls-in-css-files-with-flask)

Comment: Still getting a 404 error, should my images be inside a separate folder inside static?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the path img/ then they should be inside the img/ folder

Comment: So I added the image into a folder named img inside static, but the same error appears. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Post more information in your initial question, and we'll see :)

Comment: try static/img, perhaps

Comment: `url( img/showcase.jpeg)` is incorrect, it should be `url(../img/showcase.jpeg)`

Comment: @ParasGupta fixed it.. you are correct.. assuming your css file is in `./css` and images in `./img/(*.jpg)` - which the answer does.

Answer (score 6):

This is my directory tree structure:
[directory tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtpTv.png)

And you could write background-image like this:

```
background-image: url(../img/nodejsEventLoop.png);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
background-image: url('/static/showcase.jpeg');
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
background-image: url('../images/pic.png');
```

where `static->images->pic.png`.