# CSS + Flask issue. Need "background-image" property

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I would like to set a background image for a Flask project. I keep getting a 404 error with the .jpeg I am trying to set.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Par</title>
</head>
<style>
#divone {
background-image: url(prague.jpg);
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="divone">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the flask output

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2023 13:06:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2023 13:06:27] "GET /main HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2023 13:06:27] "GET /prague.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938957/css-background-images-with-flask) answers your question?